# in android how to send and receive special sms without showing notification and also should not be visible in inbox and outbox

Tags: android

I want to send some special sms which should not show any notification while sending and also should not be visible in the messaging app.
And for receiving sms I have a broadcast listner.
Here also if I receive sms with a special string which I want, then that msg should not show any notification and also should not save that msg into the inbox of the builtin app.

Please help me with this code.

For sending a msg I have a contentobserver and a broadcaster for incoming.
How to code so that it will be not visible in the inbox and in the outbox.

Comment: Please show exactly what you have so far and at which point you need help. This community is not here to give you a full tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think it's necessary to allow the user confirming whether to send SMS or not

Comment: this will work with incoming messages but for special outgoing messages i have contectobserver to detect them, but how to stop them to go into outbox ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create your custom broadcast receiver. 
This is a sample code which I am using and its working fine on all devices

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        Object [] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        String Sms , Number ;
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        //sms variable storing the actual message in string format

        Sms = sms.getDisplayMessageBody().toString();

        //Number Variable storing the number of recepient who send message
        Number = sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress().toString();

        String CallingNumber = "your target number";

        if(Number.contains(CallingNumber)){
        if (Sms.equalsIgnoreCase("Special key word you want to keep track on"))
        {

            Intent  intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("Number", Number);
            intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent2);
            //it will stop sending message into the Inbox
            abortBroadcast();

        }

        }
    }

}
```

For sending Message it is pretty easy

```
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage("your recipient num here", null, "Your Message here", null, null);
```